# Linear types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, linear-types

[Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/) has a linear type system. Is there any (good) way to simulate this in OCaml? E.g., when using ocaml-lua, I want to make sure some functions are called only when Lua is in a specific state (table on top of stack, etc).

**Edit**: Here's a recent paper about resource polymorphism relevant to the question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02796

**Edit 2**: There are also a number of articles about session types in OCaml available, including syntax extensions to provide some syntactic sugar.

Comment: You can use monads to hide "linear" type handling in monadic bind and only export monadic type as abstract.

Comment: What do you mean by simulate? runtime checks?

Comment: No, static. With "simulate" I mean using existent type system to achieve a (close to) linear type system.

Comment: Here is some interesting research about dependent types: http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lightweight-dependent-typing.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested by John Rivers, you can use a monadic style to represent
"effectful" computation in a way that hides the linear constraint in
the effect API. Below is one example where a type `('a, 'st) t` is
used to represent computation using a file handle (whose identity is
implicit/unspoken to guarantee that it cannot be duplicated), will
product a result of type `'a` and leave the file handle in the state
`'st` (a phantom type being either "open" or "close"). You have to use
the `run` of the monad¹ to actually do anything, and its type ensure
that the file handles are correctly closed after use.

```
module File : sig
  type ('a, 'st) t
  type open_st = Open
  type close_st = Close

  val bind : ('a, 's1) t -> ('a -> ('b, 's2) t) -> ('b, 's2) t

  val open_ : string -> (unit, open_st) t
  val read : (string, open_st) t
  val close : (unit, close_st) t

  val run : ('a, close_st) t -> 'a
end = struct
  type ('a, 'st) t = unit -> 'a
  type open_st = Open
  type close_st = Close

  let run m = m ()

  let bind m f = fun () ->
    let x = run m in
    run (f x)

  let close = fun () ->
    print_endline "[lib] close"

  let read = fun () ->
    let result = "toto" in
    print_endline ("[lib] read " ^ result);
    result

  let open_ path = fun () -> 
    print_endline ("[lib] open " ^ path)
end    

let test =
  let open File in
  let (>>=) = bind in
  run begin
    open_ "/tmp/foo" >>= fun () ->
    read >>= fun content ->
    print_endline ("[user] read " ^ content);
    close
  end

(* starting with OCaml 4.13, you can use binding operators:
   ( let* ) instead of ( >>= ) *)
let test =
  let open File in
  let ( let* ) = bind in
  run begin
    let* () = open_ "/tmp/foo" in
    let* content = read in
    print_endline ("[user] read " ^ content);
    close
  end
```

Of course, this is only meant to give you a taste of the style of
API. For more serious uses, see Oleg's [monadic
regions](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/regions.html) examples.

You may also be interested in the research programming language
[Mezzo](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Eprotzenk/mezzo-lang/), which aims to
be a variant of ML with finer-grained control of state (and related
effectful patterns) through a linear typing discipline with separated
resources. Note that it is only a research experiment for now, not
actually aimed at users. [ATS](http://ats-lang.org/) is also relevant,
though finally less ML-like. Rust may actually be a reasonable
"practical" counterpart to these experiments.

¹: it is actually not a monad because it has no `return`/`unit` combinator, but the point is to force type-controlled sequencing as the monadic `bind` operator does. It could have a `map`, though.

Comment: Could you please provide a usage example too? I haven't really got this monad thing yet. :P

Comment: @OlleHärstedt: there is an usage example at the end (`let test ...`). Or do you want something else?

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it be possible to define a phantom type that exactly corresponds to the state of the stack? When communicating between Lua and OCaml/C, we use a stack:
`Lua.newtable state;; (* Put new table on stack *)
Lua.pushstring state "index";; (* Put table index on stack *)`
So the phantom type would now be something like `[string, table]`.

Comment: How do you alternatingly read lines from 2 files and write them to a thrird?

Comment: Maybe we can rewrite this example using the new `let*` syntax?